# What's the replacement for deprecated DefaultUriTemplateHandler for RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

Pre-Spring 5, the usual way to configure the RestTemplate for accessing single REST host was as follows:

```
DefaultUriTemplateHandler uriTemplateHandler = new DefaultUriTemplateHandler();
uriTemplateHandler.setBaseUrl("http://host:port");
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(uriTemplateHandler);
```

so that when making REST calls, one can do `restTemplate.getForObject("/api/foo")` instead of `restTemplate.getForObject("http://host:port/api/foo")` (and possibly configure the REST root URL somewhere centralized)

In Spring 5, `DefaultUriTemplateHandler` is deprecated, and the suggested replacement is `DefaultUriBuilderFactory`. However, while the `RestTemplate` still has the `setUriTemplateHandler` method, it has no setter accepting an `UriBuilderFactory`, nor an `UriBuilderFactory` has anything resembling `setBaseUrl`

What is the proper replacement for this configuration pattern in Spring 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, the `UriBuilderFactory` extends `UriTemplateHandler`, so while the setter method in `RestTemplate` stays the same, one can use an `UriBuilderFactory` instance there:

```
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory());
```

As for the baseUrl setting, this has been made into fluent components with `UriBuilderFactory`, so the whole setting now can take just one line:

```
restTemplate.setUriTemplateHandler(new DefaultUriBuilderFactory("http://host:port"));
```

They really should document this change better, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Atlassian are using the deprecated on their Swagger validator. Not even they knew how to replace it with the correct non-deprecated version.